# IntelliJ continues code in REST method after stopping

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot backend. I am using IntelliJ. I am debugging my rest method.

I have noticed the following weird behaviour:

When I am debugging and I am e.g. at line 22. When I now stop the process (by clicking the red stop button in IntelliJ), the application stops, but I noticed that the the rest of the method is still executed.

Is that the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

OK the behavious is normal. The solution is:

Please enable "Kill the debug process immediately" option in "Settings (Preferences)| Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger"